Sutton & Barto: Exercise 7.11 mistake?
Exercise from the book:
7.11 Show that if the approximate action values are unchanging, then the tree-backup return (7.16) can be written as a sum of expectation-based TD errors:
$$
\begin{align*}
&G_{t:t+n} = Q(S_t, A_t) + \sum_{k=t}^{min(t+n-1,T-1)} \delta_k \prod_{i=t+1}^{k} \gamma \pi(A_i | S_i),\\
&G_{T-1:h} = R_T\\
&G_{h:h} = R_h + \sum_a (\pi (a|S_h) Q(A_h, S_h)) \text{, where }h < T-1\\
&\text{ where: } \delta_t = R_{t+1} + \gamma  \bar{V}_t(S_{t+1} - Q(S_t, A_t)
\end{align*}
$$
Question: Ain't $G_{t:t+n} = Q(S_t, A_t) + \sum_{k=t}^{min(t+n-1,T-1)} \delta_k \prod_{i=t+1}^{k} \gamma \pi(A_i | S_i)$ missing return for $G_{h:h}$ in case $ h < T-1$?
Here is my solution, I wonder if there is mistake or $G_{h:h}$ really should be included in sum?
my solution:
$$
\begin{align*}
&G_{t:t+n} = R_{t+1} + \gamma \sum_{a \neq A_{t+1}} \pi(a|S_{t+1}) Q(S_{t+1},a)  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1})G_{t+1:t+n}\\
&=  R_{t+1} + \gamma \sum_{a \neq A_{t+1}} \pi(a|S_{t+1}) Q(S_{t+1},a)  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1})G_{t+1:t+n}  + \gamma \pi(A_{t+1}|S_{t+1}) Q(S_{t+1},A_{t+1}) - \gamma \pi(A_{t+1}|S_{t+1}) Q(S_{t+1},A_{t+1})\\
&= R_{t+1} + \gamma  \bar{V}_t(S_{t+1}) + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1})G_{t+1:t+n} - \gamma \pi(A_{t+1}|S_{t+1}) Q(S_{t+1},A_{t+1}) = R_{t+1} + \gamma  \bar{V}_t(S_{t+1}) + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) (G_{t+1:t+n} -  Q(S_{t+1},A_{t+1}))\\
&= R_{t+1} + \gamma  \bar{V}_t(S_{t+1}) + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) (G_{t+1:t+n} -  Q(S_{t+1},A_{t+1})) + Q(S_t, A_t) - Q(S_t, A_t)\\
&= Q(S_t, A_t) + \delta_t  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) (G_{t+1:t+n} -  Q(S_{t+1},A_{t+1}))\\
&= Q(S_t, A_t) + \delta_t  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) (R_{t+2} + \gamma \sum_{a \neq A_{t+2}} \pi(a|S_{t+2}) Q(S_{t+2},a)  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+2} | S_{t+2})G_{t+2:t+n} -  Q(S_{t+1},A_{t+1}))\\
&= Q(S_t, A_t) + \delta_t  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) (R_{t+2} + \gamma \sum_{a \neq A_{t+2}} \pi(a|S_{t+2}) Q(S_{t+2},a)  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+2} | S_{t+2})G_{t+2:t+n} -  Q(S_{t+1},A_{t+1}) + \gamma \pi(A_{t+2}|S_{t+2}) Q(S_{t+2},A_{t+2}) - \gamma \pi(A_{t+2}|S_{t+2}) Q(S_{t+2},A_{t+2}))\\
&= Q(S_t, A_t) + \delta_t  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) (\delta_{t+1} + \gamma \pi (A_{t+2} | S_{t+2})G_{t+2:t+n} - \gamma \pi(A_{t+2}|S_{t+2}) Q(S_{t+2},A_{t+2}))\\
&= Q(S_t, A_t) + \delta_t  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) \delta_{t+1} +  \gamma^2 \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) \pi (A_{t+2} | S_{t+2})(G_{t+2:t+n} - Q(S_{t+2},A_{t+2}))\\
&= Q(S_t, A_t) + \delta_t  + \gamma \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) \delta_{t+1} +  \gamma^2 \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) \pi (A_{t+2} | S_{t+2}) \delta_{t+2} + ... + \gamma^{t+n-t} \pi (A_{t+1} | S_{t+1}) \pi (A_{t+2} | S_{t+2})...\pi (A_{t+n} | S_{t+n}))(R_{t+n} + \sum_a (\pi (a|S_{t+n}) Q(S_{t+n}, a)) - Q(S_{t+n},A_{t+n})) \\
&= Q(S_t, A_t) + (R_{t+n} + \sum_a (\pi (a|S_{t+n}) Q(S_{t+n}, a)) - Q(S_{t+n},A_{t+n})) \prod_{k=t+1}^{min(t+n,T-1)} \gamma \pi (A_k, S_k) + \sum_{k=t}^{min(t+n-1,T-1)} \delta_k \prod_{i=t+1}^{k} \gamma \pi(A_i | S_i) Q(S_t, A_t) \\
\end{align*}
$$

+1 even only for having taken the time to write this whole thing down in latex
